# How to force stops one or more services that is in a state of 'stop pending'

Tags: windows, powershell, service

I want to stop a Windows service and it's hung or stuck with a status of `Stopping`. We are using mixed operating systems such as Windows 2008/2012R2.

```
$ServerList = 'C:\Powershell\SCXAgentDSC\list.txt'  
$SCXAgents = Get-Content -Path $ServerList  

foreach ($scxagent in $SCXAgents) {
  $Hostname = $scxagent
  Write-Host $Hostname
  #Ping host
  $IP = (Test-Connection $hostname -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProtocolAddress)
  if ($IP -eq $null) {
    continue
  }
  #Get state of service 
  $servicestate = Get-Service -ComputerName $Hostname service_name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  #If service is stopped or does not exist, continue otherwise set to stopped and disabled
  if ($servicestate.status -eq 'Stopped' -or $servicestate.status -eq $null) {
    continue
  } else {
    (Get-Service -ComputerName $Hostname service_name).Stop()
    Set-Service -ComputerName $Hostname -Name service_name -StartupType Disabled
    Write-Host "stopped services" -BackgroundColor yellow
    $RPMLines = Get-Service -ComputerName $Hostname service_name

    if ($RPMLines.status -match "Stopped") {
      $ServiceStatus = "STOPPED"
    } else {
      $ServiceStatus = "RUNNING"
    }
    # Port testing (22 and 1270)
    try {
      if ((New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient("$scxagent", "1270")).Connected -eq $true) {
        $AgentPortStatus = "OK"
      } else {
        $AgentPortStatus = "NOT OK"
      }
    } catch {
      $AgentPortStatus = "NOT OK"
    }
    try {
      if ((New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient("$scxagent", "22")).Connected) {
        $sshstatus = "OK"
      } else {
        $sshstatus = "NOT OK"
      }
    } catch {
      $sshstatus = "NOT OK"
    }

    Write-Output "$scxagent | SSH : $sshstatus | AgentPort : $AgentPortStatus | AgentServStatus : $ServiceStatus"
  }
}
```

Also, Above my code I'd like to have output formatted into the one line, am I correct?  e.g.:

```
scxagent       sshstatus     AgentPortStatus    AgentServStatus
Server1        OK            OK                 STOPPED
Server2        NOT OK        NOT OK             RUNNING
etc.
```

Last Update:

```
if (-not ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]"Administrator")) {
  $arguments = "& '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
  Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
  break
}

$ServerList = 'C:\Powershell\SCXAgentDSC\list.txt'  
$SCXAgents = Get-Content -Path $ServerList  

foreach ($scxagent in $SCXAgents) {
  $Hostname = $scxagent
  Write-Host $Hostname
  #Ping host
  $IP = (Test-Connection $hostname -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProtocolAddress)
  if ($IP -eq $null) {
    continue
  }
  #Get state of service 
  $servicestate = Get-Service -ComputerName $Hostname service_name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  #If service is stopped or does not exist, continue otherwise set to stopped and disabled
  if ($servicestate.Status -eq 'Stopped' -or $servicestate.Status -eq $null) {
    continue
  } else {
    $pid = Get-WmiObject -Computer $hostname -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='service_name'" |
           Select-Object -Expand ProcessID

    (Get-Process -Computer $hostname -PID $pid).Kill()

    (Get-Service -ComputerName $Hostname service_name).Stop()
    Set-Service -ComputerName $Hostname -Name service_name -StartupType Disabled
    Write-Host "stopped services" -BackgroundColor yellow

    $RPMLines = Get-Service -ComputerName $Hostname service_name

    if ($RPMLines.Status -match "Stopped") {
      $ServiceStatus = "stop"
    } else {
      $ServiceStatus = "start"
    }
    # Port testing (22 and 1270)
    try {
      if ((New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient("$scxagent", "1270")).Connected -eq $true ) {
        $AgentPortStatus = "OK"
      } else {
        $AgentPortStatus = "NOT OK"
      }
    } catch {
      $AgentPortStatus = "NOT OK"
    }
    try {
      if ((New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient("$scxagent", "22")).Connected) {
        $sshstatus = "OK"
      } else {
        $sshstatus = "NOT OK"
      }
    } catch {
      $sshstatus = "NOT OK"
    }

    Write-Output "$scxagent | SSH : $sshstatus | AgentPort : $AgentPortStatus | AgentServStatus : $ServiceStatus"

    Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to continue"
  }
}
```

Error Message:

```
ERROR: Cannot overwrite variable PID because it is read-only or constant.
getservice.ps1 (32): ERROR: At Line: 32 char: 3
ERROR: +         $pid = Get-WmiObject -Computer $hostname -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='A ...
ERROR: +    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ERROR:     + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (PID:String) [], SessionStateUnauthorizedAccessException
ERROR:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableNotWritable
```

Comment: Usually this happen when process related to the service "stuck". You need to found the process and kill it with stop-process, then try to stop the service again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a service hangs after receiving a stop request the only way to "force-stop" it is killing the process, as [@autsvet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39556860/powershell-how-to-force-stops-one-or-more-services-that-is-in-a-state-of-stop#comment66424770_39556860) already mentioned. Use the PID to identify the process:

```
$processID = Get-WmiObject -Computer $hostname -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='service_name'" |
             Select-Object -Expand ProcessID

(Get-Process -Computer $hostname -PID $processID).Kill()
```

Note that some services are configured to not allow tampering with their process. In such cases you could try to [change the process settings](https://superuser.com/a/110202/156043). If that doesn't work (or you can't do it for some reason) you'll have to resort to rebooting the system.

Comment: Only you can tell if the output of your code is what you intend it to be. Also please do not mix questions. Focus your questions on one problem at a time.

Comment: I am understading you very well But I just dont want to open new question related to this. Well Can I take a little idea ?

Comment: I am getting an error like "ERROR: Cannot overwrite variable PID because it is read-only or constant."

Comment: Edit your question and show your updated code as well as the complete error message.

Comment: *\*slaps self\** Sorry, my mistake. `$PID` is an [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx), so you need to use a different variable name.

Comment: I am getting different error message at this time. Exception calling "Stop" with "0" argument(s): "Cannot open service on computer '.'."
At line:35 char:3
+ (Get-Service -ComputerName $Hostname service_name).STOP() <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException  is it required refresh method?

Comment: What's the point of trying to stop a service after you already killed its process? Just remove that statement.

Comment: After Kill() statement  I want to stop those services. So I have to use "(Get-Service -ComputerName $Hostname service_name).STOP() ".  So first kill  process then stop service.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Once you killed the process the service is already dead, so there's nothing to stop anymore. Also, just to be clear, you should **NOT** attempt to kill the process of a service unless it failed to respond to a stop request.